# How to find out did the user click a button or pressed the escape key when WPF Button IsCancel Property is used

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a button defined like this:

```
<Button IsCancel="true" Click="PopupCloseButton_Click">x</Button>
```

Is there a way to know which one of the two actions brought us to `PopupCloseButton_Click`, the click or the "esc" key?

---

Currently I am using a **different** method to achive this, but it would be nice if `IsCancel` can be used instead.
For sake of completeness here is my current way in xaml:

```
<Border Focusable="True" PreviewKeyDown="PopupWindow_PreviewKeyDown">
```

The element (Border) should be `.Focus()` and in xaml.cs:

```
private void PopupWindow_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
        {
            HidePopup();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You answered your own question. Any event that passes KeyEventArgs will let you know which key is pressed.

Comment: @kurakura88 I am not sure what you mean? My question is: How to find out what (key or mouse click) was used in PopupCloseButton_Click, when the button IsCancel is true.

Comment: Regardless of `IsCancel` property, to know what key is pressed, you need to handle `PreviewKeyDown` event (which passes `KeyEventArgs` argument) like you wrote. If you know that your `PreviewKeyDown` event handler is not handling it, then you can automatically/ safely think that it is from other input (such as: button invoke, mouse click, or touch). If you wanted to know specifically if it is from mouse, you can handle `PreviewMouseDown` event. But, this is like doing extra work. Why do you need to know where the input is from to begin with? A button should only have a command bound to it.

Comment: @kurakura88 Right, I see your point. Seems that its not possible to know which exact action led us to PopupCloseButton_Click, without making an assumption. I will just use the second approach. Thanks!

Comment: If you are planning to have multiple commands based on input, you should use [InputBindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.inputbinding?view=netcore-3.1). Do not use `ClickEvent` handler.